# Flutter: ios OK, android crashing on startup without error

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, android-emulator

I'm fairly confident this has something to do with the package name or firebase, but I've tried everything I could find on this issue in existing questions. I have triple-checked that:

- The package name is the same in MainActivity.kt, app/build.gradle, and AndroidManifest.xml
- The path to the Kotlin file is updated to android/app/main/kotlin/com/takaomatt/together (my package name is com.takaomatt.together)
- Restarted emulators multiple times, deleting and recreating in AVD manager in Android Studio.
- Deleted cache/memory & uninstalled apps on emulators multiple times.
- Running `flutter clean` multiple times.

I can't find anything else to try.

I get the same behavior for Pixel 2 and Pixel 2 XL emulators. All ios emulators are working totally fine.

The app flashes white briefly on startup before crashing. Here are the tail of the logs by running `flutter run -v`, it just hangs on the last output forever.

```
[  +30 ms] Stopping app 'app.apk' on Android SDK built for x86.
[   +1 ms] executing: /Users/takaomatt/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5554 shell am force-stop com.takaomatt.together
[ +125 ms] executing: /Users/takaomatt/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5554 shell pm list packages com.takaomatt.together
[  +61 ms] Installing APK.
[   +2 ms] executing: /Users/takaomatt/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb version
[   +8 ms] Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.40
           Version 4986621
           Installed as /Users/takaomatt/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb
[   +1 ms] executing: /Users/takaomatt/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb start-server
[   +9 ms] Installing build/app/outputs/apk/app.apk...
[   +1 ms] executing: /Users/takaomatt/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5554 install -t -r
/Users/takaomatt/flutter-projects/together/build/app/outputs/apk/app.apk
[+4537 ms] Success
[        ] Installing build/app/outputs/apk/app.apk... (completed in 4.5s)
[   +2 ms] executing: /Users/takaomatt/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5554 shell echo -n e873ff45fcf08951fa0dd832d3bb6793a37a46b3 >
/data/local/tmp/sky.com.takaomatt.together.sha1
[ +140 ms] Android SDK built for x86 startApp
[   +5 ms] executing: /Users/takaomatt/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5554 shell am start -a android.intent.action.RUN -f 0x20000000 --ez
enable-background-compilation true --ez enable-dart-profiling true --ez enable-checked-mode true --ez verify-entry-points true
com.takaomatt.together/com.takaomatt.together.MainActivity
[ +504 ms] Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.RUN flg=0x20000000 cmp=com.takaomatt.together/.MainActivity (has extras) }
[        ] Waiting for observatory port to be available...
```